# Where can I find resources about SharePoint best coding security practices?

Tags: security, sharepoint

Where can find resources about best practices for SharePoint programming?
I am talking about CODING against Sharepoint and NOT administration and deployment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WSS Developer Center on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/default.aspx). I also highly recommend Ted Pattison's book: [Inside WSS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201)

Answer (score 1):

the Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services Software Development Kit (SDK) contains the best practises document even if you want you can visit the MSDN you will find the same 1 URL is provided below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd583161.aspx